# How to copy a folder recursively in an idempotent way using cp?

Tags: cp, recursive

When I use

```
cp -R inputFolder outputFolder
```

the result is **context-dependent**:

1. if `outputFolder` does not exist, it will be created, and the cloned folder path will be `outputFolder`.
2. if `outputFolder` exists, then the clone created will be `outputFolder/inputFolder`

**This is horrible**, because I want to create some installation script, and if the user runs it twice by mistake, he will have `outputFolder` created the first time, then on the second run all the stuff will be created once again in `outputFolder/inputFolder`.

- **I want always the first behavior: create a clone next to the original (as a sibling).**
- I want to use `cp` to be portable (e.g. MINGW does not have `rsync` shipped)
- I checked `cp -R --parents` but this recreates the path all the way up the directory tree (so the clone will not be `outputFolder` but `some/path/outputFolder`)
- `--remove-destination` or `--update` in case 2 do not change anything, still things are copied into `outputFolder/inputFolder`

Is there a way to do this without first checking for existence of the `outputFolder` (if folder does not exist then...) or using `rm -rf outputFolder`?

What is the agreed, portable UNIX way of doing that?

Comment: Related: [How to prevent `mv` from moving a collection of files into a single regular one?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169186/12779)

Comment: Some of those options aren't POSIX, so the ones you tried aren't very portable. If you can live with a little lack of portability, why not use `rsync`?

Comment: If you don't need to use `cp`, piping between two `tar` commands is a nice reliable way to copy trees.

Comment: @R.. can you provide an example?
@muru I'd like this to work in MINGW which does not have `rsync` shipped.

Comment: With GNU tar, `tar -C input -cf - . | tar -C output -xf -` works. `-C` changes working directory, but it is not a standard option, so if it's not supported you need to run the two tars in the right working directories to begin with, e.g. `( cd input && tar -cf - . ) | ( cd output && tar -xf - )` However if you're dealing with Windows I would just use roaima's answer.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
cp -R inputFolder/. outputFolder
```

This works in exactly the same way that, say, `cp -R aaa/bbb ccc` works: if `ccc` doesn't exist then it's created as a copy of `bbb` and its contents; but if `ccc` already exists then `ccc/bbb` is created as the copy of `bbb` and its contents.

For almost any instance of `bbb` this gives the undesirable behaviour that you noted in your Question. However, in this specific situation the `bbb` is just `.`, so `aaa/bbb` is really `aaa/.`, which in turn is really just `aaa` but by another name. So we have these two scenarios:

1. `ccc` does not exist:

   The command `cp -R aaa/. ccc` means "create `ccc` and copy the contents of `aaa/.` into `ccc/.`, i.e. copy `aaa` into `ccc`.
2. `ccc` does exist:

   The command `cp -R aaa/. ccc` means "copy the contents of `aaa/.` into `ccc/.`, i.e. copy `aaa` into `ccc`.

Comment: Huh, that's a new one for me, but it does seem to work! It this documented anywhere?

Comment: I've tested the `inputFolder/.` instead of `inputFolder` and indeed it works for me on Windows/Git Bash. (It does not work however with just a trailing `/`, I need also the dot after the slash). I gave +1 since it's interesting, though it's probably a bit too tricky to use it in public code :)

Comment: @IlmariJaronen it doesn't need to be documented explicitly. Follow through the explanation and you'll see how it simply "follows the rules".

Answer (score 22):

Don't copy the folder, only copy the contents:

```bsh
## Create the target directory. The -p suppresses error messages
## if the directory already exists
mkdir -p outputFolder

## Copy the contents recursively, this will not recreate the parent
cp -R inputfolder/* outputfolder/
```

This way you both ensure that the target directory is created the first time the script runs and avoid the issue when running it a second time.

Chris Down very correctly points out that in bash, this will skip files whose name starts with a `.`. To avoid this, you can run `shopt -s dotglob` before running the command above.

Both [`-p` for `mkdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html) and [`-R` for `cp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html) are defined by POSIX so this should be perfectly portable.

Comment: Note: this won't copy files starting with `.`. In bash, you can use `dotglob` for that.

Comment: Note this method is likely to fail if the number of directory entries in inputfolder is large, because the glob expansion could exceed the maximum command line length.

Answer (score 12):

Try the `-T` option to `cp`. This exists in GNU coreutils `cp` version 8.22; it may not be portable outside that.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that this is exactly what I wanted: `cp -T` (`cp --no-target-directory`).

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94831/cp-no-target-directory-explained

Unfortunately my version of `cp` is much older.

Comment: +1 Used this just today. `-u` is a great option to add to make it lazy.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `rsync`:

```
rsync -uav inputFolder/ outputFolder/
```

(note the slashes, especially after the first one)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-t` option of `cp` command as:

```
cp -R inputFolder -t outputFolder
```

now if target folder does not exist it will throw an error:

```
cp: failed to access ‘outputFolder’: No such file or directory
```

note above command will copy `inputFolder` along with its content (and not just contents inside it)

if you want to copy just the contents of `inputFolder` it gets bit tricky (since you have to be careful while using shell globbing while using asterisk *)

```
cp -R  -t outputFolder/ -- inputFolder/*
```

now if target folder does not exist it will throw an error:

```
cp: failed to access ‘outputFolder’: No such file or directory
```

works with `cp (GNU coreutils) 8.23`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is nothing simpler and more portable than `rm -rf outputFolder`. So, I always stick with that. I understand that your question is different, but I think that this is the best practice.

Comment: That fails if there were specific permissions or ownerships on the target that needed to be kept. Or if it was a symlink.

Comment: The question wants the result of `cp` to be the same, both when the directory does not exist and when it exists. So, what are you talking about?

Comment: The `cp` command as given by the OP doesn't keep permissions (or timestamps).