# "Cannot create directory ... no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, directory, docker, cp

When executing the dockerfile, the command `RUN cp -rf roundcubemail-1.2.3/. /var/www/html/` is executed and I'm getting the following error:

```
cp: cannot create directory '/var/www/html/': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'mailserver' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cp -rf 
roundcubemail-1.2.3/. /var/www/html/' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

That error occurs when executing any command on that directory. I already changed the permissions to 775, but that didn't change anything.

When adding 775 to `RUN cp 775 -rf roundcubemail-1.2.3/. /var/www/html/`
the error changes to "is not a directory".

Comment: I assume this is a Docker question? If it is, can you specify that in your question and post your Dockerfile?

Comment: `/var/www/html` exists and is a directory?

Comment: The commands are run using `sh -c`, which means the command possibly has to be quoted.

Comment: @roaima Yes i checked it with [ -d "/path/to/dir" ]

Comment: *inside* the container, though? `cp` will report that error if the `/var/www` does not exist

Comment: @JeffSchaller How to chek if it's inside the container?

Comment: Actually, given the `cp` command, just `/var/www` needs to exist (as a directory). It'll create `html` if necessary, but not complain if it already exists.

Comment: @roaima So any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp` will report that error if the parent directory (`www` in this case) does not exist:

```
$ mkdir src dest
$ touch src/file
$ cp -r src dest/www/html/
cp: cannot create directory ‘dest/www/html/’: No such file or directory
```

as opposed to:

```
$ mkdir -p dest/www/html
$ cp -r src dest/www/html/
$ find dest
dest
dest/www
dest/www/html
dest/www/html/src
dest/www/html/src/file
```

Also, I believe your:

> ```
> RUN cp 775 -rf roundcubemail-1.2.3/. /var/www/html/
> ```

command is potentially a reference to the `install -m` command, which accepts a `MODE` to set on copied files. `cp`, on the other hand, is simply expecting a list of source directories, and so that command is looking for three files/directories to copy to `/var/www/html/`:

1. `755`
2. `-rf`
3. `roundcubemail-1.2.3`

To solve this particular issue, I would recommend adding this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
```

Comment: what are src and dest for?

Comment: I didn't feel like clobbering my existing /var/www/html directory to test, so those are just example directories to demonstrate the behavior (and the solution).

Comment: In your example, if you change the source from `src` to `src/.` it will either use the existing target or create it. See [How to copy a folder recursively in an idempotent way using cp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228637/100397).

Comment: So I need to add a ' RUN mkdir -p var/www/html
RUN cp -r src/ var/www/html/ ' in front of the other commands?

Comment: @Orange I've updated the post with more description and a suggestion for solving the problem

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll test this tomorrow. :)