# cp -a doesn't work to copy all files inside a directory

Tags: directory, cp, recursive, gnu

I desire to copy all files inside a directory which has only these files (all are regular files - there are no directories, symlinks, etc, inside that directory) to another pre-existing directory.

The files have pretty common names like `robots.txt` and don't follow any specific pattern.

I tried a similar command:

```shell
cp -a "$HOME"/a "$HOME"/b
```

I understand that `-a` is a shortcut-combo for `-d` (preserving mode, ownership and timestamps) and `-R` which orders recursive copying.

If copying is recursive, why the files aren't copied and what would be a solution?

Comment: Is `$HOME/b` a pre-existing directory? Did you look inside it?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. Edited.

Comment: The paragraph “In practice there…`cp file1 ... "$HOME"/a "$HOME"/b`…” is wrong.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor hello, what's wrong please?

Comment: it is not equivalent: try it.

Comment: I don't understand - this is just an example command; I believe you understood the paths are different so i miss in-equivalence.

Comment: If you incorrect syntax in your example, assuming we know what you mean, we could assume you are using incorrect syntax that is causing your problem...that's all ctrl-alt-delor is probably indicating.

Comment: I changed the three dots to file names; I assume now @ctrl-alt-delor meant that.

Comment: No `cp file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 "$HOME"/a "$HOME"/b` means: copy file1, file2, ... and $HOME/a into $HOME/b. (But not recursively)

Comment: Dear @ctrl-alt-delor thank you so much. I fixed it. This is a classical example of why community is important.

Comment: When you are not understanding what is happening, just put -v together with your cp command....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scenarios:

1. Directory `a` exists but `b` doesn't`:

   ```bash
   cp -a "$HOME"/a "$HOME"/b
   ```

   will copy the entire directory `a` to a new directory `b`
2. Directories `a` and `b` exist:

   ```bash
   cp -a "$HOME"/a "$HOME"/b
   ```

   will copy the directory `a` *inside* directory `b`. So you'll get a `"$HOME"/b/a` directory as a result.
3. Directories `a` and `b` exist:

   ```bash
   cp -a "$HOME"/a/* "$HOME"/b
   ```

   will copy the *contents* of `a` *inside* directory `b` but exclude hidden files and directories. While some shells have some options to include them, here the best approach would be:

   ```bash
   cp -a ~/a/. ~/b/
   ```

   This is what I understand you want.

Comment: Note that the very last command would not copy hidden files. This may not be an issue in this particular case, but it may well be an issue in the general case. To solve that, enable globbing of hidden files (in `bash`: `shopt -s dotglob`, in `zsh`: `setopt GLOB_DOTS`).

Comment: Change the star for a dot in the last command and it'll copy everything in `a` for you. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228637/100397) for the explanation.

Comment: So much time passed since I last used shell globs - I forgot I have to use them here... A trouble of being a shell scripting amateur.

Comment: @Kusalananda, in `zsh`, you'd rather use `cp -a "$HOME"/a/*(D) "$HOME"/b` to include hidden files rather than change a global setting. But `cp -a ~/a/. ~/b/` would be best.

Answer (score 0):

`cp` safety tips:

## copying a directory

### Directories a and b exist:

```bash
    cp -a a b/
    cp -a -t b a
```

will copy the directory `a` into directory `b`.

### Directory a exists but b doesn't:

```bash
    cp -a a b/
    cp -a -t b a
```

will generate a friendly error message

## copying a file

### Directory b exists

```bash
    cp -T a b
```

will generate a friendly error message

### Directory b does not exist

```bash
   cp -T a b
```

will copy the file, to b

---

Note not all versions of cp/mv/ln have the `-t` or `-T` options, but all allow the `/` to ensure that the `b` is a directory. If they don't have these options, then there is no way to guarantee that `b` is not an existing directory.

Comment: Not all implementations of `cp` have the `-T` option. Furthermore, some implementations require `/.` instead of just `/`. For example `cp -a a/. b` rather than `cp -a a/ b`. (And all implementations handle it, so there's no harm including the trailing dot on the source directory.)

Comment: I have already added a note about `-T` not being in all implementations.

Comment: Yes... but on that same note, just `/` on its own also doesn't work everywhere, but `/.` (with that trailing dot) does.

Comment: @roaima can you edit the answer.