# cp -r: trigger "No such file or directory" error instead of creating "dst"

Tags: cp

Case 1: If `dst` does not exist, then `cp -vr src dst` creates `dst` and copies all the content from `src` to `dst`:

```
$ cp -vr src dst
'src' -> 'dst'
'src/t0.c' -> 'dst/t0.c'
```

Case 2: If `dst` does exist, then `cp -vr src dst` creates `dst/src` and copies all the content from `src` to `dst/src`:

```
$ cp -vr src dst
'src' -> 'dst/src'
'src/t0.c' -> 'dst/src/t0.c'
```

Question: For `case 1`: is there any option that will make `cp` trigger `No such file or directory` error instead of creating `dst`?

Comment: Related if not a duplicate - [How to copy a folder recursively in an idempotent way using cp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228637/100397)

Comment: ↑ it doesn't generate an error but it makes `cp` work in a consistent manner regardless of whether or not `dst` exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the cp of GNU coreutils:

```
cp -rt dst src/.
```

Notice the reverse order of the arguments -- in fact, `dst` is an argument of the `-t`, `--target-directory` [option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Target-directory).