# If cp's destination path turns out to be a directory, how do I avoid mistakenly creating files inside that directory?

Tags: files, cp

My understanding of `cp src dest` is:

1. If `src` is a file and `dest` doesn't exist, but its parent directory does, `dest` is created.
2. If `src` is a file and `dest` is a file, `dest` is overwritten with the contents of `src`.
3. **If `src` is a file and `dest` is a directory, `dest/src` is created.**

I'm trying to avoid case #3. If I write a script assuming that `dest` *won't* be a directory, but it turns out at runtime that it *is,* I don't want `cp` to put a file in the wrong place and continue silently.

Instead, I want it to either:

- Delete the whole `dest` directory and replace it with the desired file.
- Error out without doing anything.

I'd also prefer for this to happen atomically. Using a separate command like `test -d` to check if `dest` is a directory would open up an opportunity for TOCTTOU problems.

Can this be done with `cp`? If not, can it be done with any other similarly ubiquitous command?

I'm interested in both portable solutions and solutions that rely on non-standard extensions, as long as they're reasonably common.

Comment: Do you use GNU coreutils?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk No, I happen to not use GNU coreutils. But I'm interested in hearing about non-standard extensions in addition to more portable options, even if I can't necessarily use them right now.

Comment: It's a shame because GNU cp `-T, --no-target-directory` would do what you want. What implementation of cp do you use then?

Comment: Related - [How to copy a folder recursively in an idempotent way using cp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228597/how-to-copy-a-folder-recursively-in-an-idempotent-way-using-cp)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I sometimes work on machines with BusyBox `cp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A redirection would do that. It behaves as `cp`'s `-T, --no-target-directory` (it exits with error if `dst` is a directory):

```
$ cat src > dst
```

Comment: `dd` would be another option.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of absolute compatibility, you could check for a target directory before attempting the copy.

Either error out,

```
[ -d dest ] && echo "${0##*/}: is a directory: dest" >&2 && exit 1
cp src dest
```

or remove the target silently

```
[ -d dest ] && rm -rf dest
cp src dest
```

There is no atomic operation available to delete a directory and replace it with a file. (You might find a command such as `cp --no-target-directory`, but the underlying operation is still fundamentally not atomic. All you're doing is reducing the attack surface, not eliminating it.)

Comment: But OP said `I'd also prefer for this to happen atomically. Using a separate command like test -d to check if dest is a directory would open up an opportunity for TOCTTOU problems.`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk point noted; I was in the process of flagging up a race condition in the second option so I've modified what I was going say in favour of addressing your concern