# mv: cannot move "File exists"

Tags: linux, rhel, mv, move

When trying to move  some folder I am getting error: "cannot move File exists"

```
export BACKUP_DIR=/backup
mv -f $BACKUP_DIR/scripts $BACKUP_DIR/scripts_old
```

Getting error:

```
mv: cannot move '/backup/scripts' to '/backup/scripts_old/scripts': File exists
```

I've tried with `-f` option but without it as well  - same error.
How I can move this?

Thanks!

Comment: @they `scripts_old` is folder and it contains as well folder `scripts` which I want to overwrite
`drwxr-xr-x. scripts_old`

Comment: Sorry, I did not spot that this was already mentioned in the error message that you quoted.

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228597/100397

Comment: @roaima I think it's not related!!!!!! `-R` option cannot be used for `mv`.
output: `mv: invalid option -- 'R' `
sorry but your link is not valid solution

Comment: I know it's not a valid solution, but it's definitely related. I'm just writing a full answer for you!

Comment: Do you want to merge or overwrite as in "delete the old directory and contents then replace by new directory and contens"?

Comment: @FelixJN I would like to overwrite as that is the folder. So to put additional folder instead of the previous one but without introducing additional `rm` command before the `mv`

Comment: @FelixJN ok thanks a lot for your assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this cannot be done without a separate removal.

`rsync`  allows to a) remove source files (but files only) via `--remove-source-files` and b) delete files in target that do not exist in source (`--delete`). Best to be used with `-nv` to make a verbose dry-run. Depending on the version of `rsync`, `-r`ecursivity may be needed.

Nevertheless this you will have the empty directory tree left in `source` and directories not mentioned in `source` will remain untouched in `target`.

Long story short: use two commands and the simples option would be:

```
rm "$BACKUP_DIR"/scripts_old &&
mv "$BACKUP_DIR"/scripts "$BACKUP_DIR"/scripts_old
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot merge existing directories with `mv`. The error message comes about because `scripts` already exists in `/backup/scripts_old`.

What you can do, though, is to copy/link the files across and then remove the linked files from the source. The solution here requires GNU (non-POSIX) `cp` and only works if the source and destination are on the same filesystem:

```
BACKUP_DIR=/backup
cp -al "$BACKUP_DIR"/scripts/. "$BACKUP_DIR"/scripts_old/scripts
find "$BACKUP_DIR"/scripts -type f -links 2 -print
```

Notes

- The trailing dot (`.`) on the copy source [is essential](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228597/100397)
- Change `-print` to `-delete` when you're happy it's going to delete the correct files from the source
- Double-quote your variables when you use them (otherwise directories with spaces in their name will break your code horribly)
- If you don't have GNU `cp` with the option to create links instead of copies, then `rsync` or `pax` can suffice

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify why `-al` options are required? why is archive important and why do you want to create hard links instead of copying? I don't want to create hard links

Comment: Doesn't this also require that source and target be on the same file system?

Comment: According to the comments, OP is not interest in merging, but the equivalent of removing target and replacing it with source (without trace of the previous contents).

Comment: @FelixJN changing the requirements in comments? They haven't changed in the question. This is why it's so important to keep all the necessary information in one place. And answers shouldn't be in comments either

Comment: Whether "move" should mean "merge" or "fully replace" can at least be argued and the original question allows for either interpretation - the question simply needs an update for more clarity. Agreed on my comment having gotten a bit out of hand - it didn't fulfill the "single command" requirement, but after all it is more of an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 3):

The `mv` command does not support replacing directories, as this is a very dangerous operation.  If you did this accidentally, you would lose all the data in the target directory.

If you don't want to merge the two folders, you will have to rename or delete the target folder `$BACKUP_DIR/scripts_old/scripts` before attempting the mv.  This can't be bypassed.

Here are your options:

- Delete the target directory first
- Put the source directory into the target directory as `$BACKUP_DIR/scripts_old/scripts/scripts`
- Rename either the source or target directory, e.g., `$BACKUP_DIR/scripts_old/scripts1`
- merge the directories (but this might overwrite files or have additional directory collisions) `mv scripts/* $BACKUP_DIR/scripts_old/scripts/*` (or do something similar like the find in the other answer)
- Use something like rsync to replace files in the target directory with files from the source directory, optionally deleting the source and optionally deleting things in the target not in the source (likely this is the slowest of the options)

You didn't really explain why you want a backup directory like this.
Perhaps it would be better to not use a backup directory at all, but instead use a revision control tool like git.