# Copy recursively complete content of a directory

Tags: rsync, cp

I am a bit embarassed that, as a long-time linux user, I don't have an answer to this:

```
+- root-dir
+- dest
```

If I run `cp -r root-dir dest/`, then the complete content of `root-dir` is copied to `dest/`, including hidden files.

However, the result is

```
+-root-dir
+-dest
+----+ root-dir
```

If I do this though: `cp -r root-dir/* dest/`, then indeed I have all the content of `root-dir` at the `dest/` folder with desired hierarchy - but the hidden files are **not** copied.

How can I get an exact copy of `root-dir` into `dest` but not as a subfolder? I can't just remove `dest` and rename it later, because `dest` already has some content which should be kept (in fact these are all *git* folders).

In other words, I want to merge both directories including hidden files. I also tried `rsync -a` but that seems to also exclude hidden files.

Comment: Try [how-to-copy-a-folder-recursively-in-an-idempotent-way-using-cp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228597/how-to-copy-a-folder-recursively-in-an-idempotent-way-using-cp). In this case I think you want `cp -R root-dir/. dest`

Comment: Ah indeed! @rowboat that was the one I needed. "copying recursively" was too broad of a search to actually find what I was looking for...I was sure I wasn't the first with this issue. Thank you!