# cp, trailing slash, and copying to the same vs. to another directory

Tags: freebsd, macos, cp, slash

To copy a directory to another directory, the first directory should be written without the trailing slash:

```
# example 1
# this command will copy dir1 to dir2
# (dir2 is preexisting)
cp -Rip dir1 dir2/
```

Otherwise, the command will copy directory contents and not the directory itself:

```
# example 2
# this command will copy dir1 contents to dir2
# (dir2 is preexisting)
cp -Rip dir1/ dir2/
```

I do understand the difference between `dir1` and `dir1/` here, and the difference between how these two commands behave doesn't confuse me.

But to copy the directory not to another directory but to the same directory where it is currently located, the trailing slash won't make any difference. Why?

```
# example 3
# any of these commands will make a dir1 copy
# (dir1-copy isn't preexisting)
cp -Rip dir1 dir1-copy/
cp -Rip dir1/ dir1-copy/
```

And another, closely related question. Why there is no difference between how `mv dir1/ dir2/` and `mv dir1 dir2/` work? In other words, why, in respect of trailing slash in the end of the source directory, `mv` follows the logic of the third `cp` example, and not the logic of examples one and two?

macOS 14.3.1, zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0)

Comment: Related, I think - [How to copy a folder recursively in an idempotent way using cp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228637/100397)

Comment: In which of the cases in your question is the destination directory preexisting, and in which cases is it not?

Comment: @Kusalananda The destination directory preexisting in cases #1 and #2.

Comment: “Otherwise, the command will copy directory contents and not the directory itself” — this is wrong with any POSIX-compliant cp, and wrong with GNU cp (I just checked GNU coreutils 8.25 and 8.32). The effect of a slash on the source is to see through symbolic links, but it doesn't make a difference with non-symlink directories. How exactly did you copy the contents of `dir1` into `dir2`? On what system?

Comment: There is this feature/quirk of `rsync` where `rsync -a dir1 dir2/` and `rsync -a dir1/ dir2/` give different results. AFAIK `cp` shall not do this. Please redo your tests and confirm your `cp` behaves like you described.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' and Kamil, I checked again and don't see any inaccuracies in what I said. For you to be completely sure, here are two GIFs, for the first and second example respectively: https://gifyu.com/image/SUlNf and https://gifyu.com/image/SUlNY. They are 2.5 MB each, so I cannot upload them right here. macOS 14.3.1, zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0)

Comment: What is the output of `type -a cp`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `cp is /bin/cp`

Comment: [It seems `cp -R` in macOS is supposed to behave like `rsync` in this matter](https://ss64.com/mac/cp.html): "If the `source_file` ends in a `/`, the contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory itself". Quite a surprise for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in behavior between `cp -R dir1 dir2` and `cp -R dir1/ dir2` is a feature that was added to FreeBSD in [version 5.4](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cp&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+5.4-RELEASE). At least, that's when the following sentence was added to the manual for the description of the `-R` option:

> If the `source_file` ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory itself.

It's possible that this behavior was older and 5.4 just filled an omission in the documentation. There's nothing about this in the [5.0](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/5.0R/relnotes-i386/#USERLAND), [5.1](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/5.1R/relnotes-i386/#USERLAND), [5.2](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/5.2R/relnotes-i386/#USERLAND), [5.3](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/5.3R/relnotes-i386/#USERLAND) or [5.4](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/5.4R/relnotes-i386/#USERLAND) release notes. I haven't gone source diving.

Modern versions of FreeBSD, and macOS which has command line utilities from FreeBSD, have kept this behavior. Other systems (GNU, BusyBox, OpenBSD, NetBSD, or anything POSIX-compliant) don't have this behavior: `cp -R dir1/ dir2` and `cp -R dir1 dir2` have exactly the same behavior (except when `dir1` is a symbolic link: `dir1/` causes the link to be followed).

The FreeBSD behavior may have been inspired by rsync, which has the same distinction. I do find it strange that they made a backward-incompatible change that deviated

> But to copy the directory not to another directory but to the same directory where it is currently located, the trailing slash won't make any difference. Why?

It's a weird design decision. Or maybe it wasn't a design decision, but an implementation bug (parsing the source path and deciding that the part after the trailing slash is a path component) that they decided to call a feature. With rsync, the trailing slash keeps its behavior even when the destination directory doesn't exist.

> Why there is no difference between how `mv dir1/ dir2/` and `mv dir1 dir2/` work?

There isn't supposed to be a difference (assuming `dir1` isn't a symbolic link), so that's just the normal state of affairs.